# Celery Backend Enabled, Results Say Otherwise

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, backend, amqp

I'll keep it short and to the point:

**project directory**

```
proj/__init__.py
    /tasks.py
    /celery_app.py
```

**celery_app.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
         broker='amqp://',
         backend='amqp://',
         include=['proj.tasks'])

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import current_app
from celery.contrib.methods import task_method

class A:

    @current_app.task(filter=task_method)
    def add(self,x, y):
        return x + y
```

**worker log**

```
 -------------- celery@mycomp.localdomain v3.1.17 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-6.6-Final
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x1dc12d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 24 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . proj.tasks.add

[2015-04-08 17:45:20,788: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2015-04-08 17:45:20,801: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-04-08 17:45:21,812: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-04-08 17:45:21,828: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@mycomp.localdomain ready.
[2015-04-08 17:50:25,610: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: proj.tasks.add[e0020f67-dbe7-4f6d-9547-a8ace36c2a2c]
[2015-04-08 17:50:25,635: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.add[e0020f67-dbe7-4f6d-9547-a8ace36c2a2c] succeeded in 0.023062946042s: 4
```

**python shell**

```
>>> from proj.tasks import A
>>> a = A()
>>> s = a.add.delay(2,2)
>>> s
<AsyncResult: e0020f67-dbe7-4f6d-9547-a8ace36c2a2c>
>>> s.backend
<celery.backends.base.DisabledBackend object at 0x113fdd0>
```

As you can see, I have a backend enabled. I'm using amqp. However, when I try and get the result, it's saying I dont have an enabled backend.

Answer (score 1):

By including the line `from proj.celery_app import app` in tasks.py, the backend started to work.

This seems like a bug, since current_app should contain that backend instance.

I opened an issue on the celery github. Hopefully this helps anyone who encounters this problem as well.

[Link to the github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2568)